# How to include DLLs to published application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my solution I reference DLLs file from Libs folder. When I publishe application they don't copy to published folder. Is there anyway to make them to be copied too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your DLLs in the `Bin` folder.
The publisher will copy that folder.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Slaks I would say, in order to have DLL in bin or

Set CopyLocal property if linked reference to True.

Or

Use postbuild event to achieve the same.